# Pending (stuck) reassign partitions in Kafka manager

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

The below reassign partition operation is stuck when performed via Kafka Manager. Kafka version is 0.9.0.1.

Is the a way to understand why and let it progress?

[image]

Going to try `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` instead